# close wpf user control in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm stuck on this issue, please help.

I created an user control named **"CreateNewCase_uc"** within which  I created a button Close named **"btnClose"**

In my MainWindow, I created a Grid named **"grid1"** and a button Open named **"btnCreateNewCase"** with this code

```
Private Sub btnCreateNewCase_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim cnc As CreateNewCase_uc = New CreateNewCase_uc
        grid1.Children.Clear()
        grid1.Children.Add(cnc)
    End Sub
```

**My question :** which Code I need to Write for my bntClose button which is inside the user control to close or make disappeared the user control in VB.NET

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the Parent control then remove it.

```
' from inside your close button on UC.
Dim parent = TryCast(Me.Parent, Grid))
If Not parent Is Nothing Then 
  parent.Children.Remove(Me)
End If
```

Comment: Hi guys, I tried all the two answers and they both work, by thinking that, it's almost make me mad by trying many things that's not work.

Great THANKS for you

but DonA, please what's the difference between the two ways

Comment: @Clemens's version just changes it's `Visibilty`. My version removes the entire control which frees up some of the memory footprint, if it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Ok, well understand. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You may simply set the UserControl's Visibility to `Collapsed`:

```
Private Sub btnCreateNewCase_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Me.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
End Sub
```